# How to calculate Quadratic Bezier Curve

Tags: java, andengine, bezier

I want to put some Sprites on path. I thought about calculate bezier path and then put sprites on calculated points. But I can't find in java method to do that.

---

### SOLVED

This is my main method to draw line of images

```
private List<Sprite> drawStarLine(Point start, Point end, Point control1, Point control2, int starsCount,TextureRegion pTexture) {
    ArrayList<Sprite> starsForReturn = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(generateBezierPath(start, end, control1, control2, starsCount));
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point p = points.get(i);
        Sprite s = new Sprite((float) p.getX(), (float) p.getY(), pTexture, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        s.setScale(mainScaleX / 2);
        starsForReturn.add(s);
    }
    return starsForReturn;
}
```

This is how I calculate bezier path

```
private List<Point> generateBezierPath(Point origin, Point destination, Point control1, Point control2, int segments) {
    ArrayList<Point> pointsForReturn = new ArrayList<Point>();

    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.setX(Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * origin.x + 3.0f * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * t * control1.x + 3.0f * (1 - t) * t * t * control2.x + t * t * t * destination.x);
        p.setY(Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * origin.y + 3.0f * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * t * control1.y + 3.0f * (1 - t) * t * t * control2.y + t * t * t * destination.y);
        t += 1.0f / segments;
        pointsForReturn.add(p);
    }
    pointsForReturn.add(destination);
    return pointsForReturn;
}
```

Comment: Don't add your additional information as an answer: put it here, in your question, and then delete the answer you made for it. At 670 reputation, you should know all the information goes in your question =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought "share your knowledge, Q&A-style" is proper way. It isn't?

Comment: not if it's your own question. all information pertaining to your question, unless you're literally answering your own question, goes in the original post, not as follow ups.

Comment: oo good to know. I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate the quadratic curve coordinates (for position) and tangent (for orientation). The code is simple.

```
double[] getPoint(double[] x, double[] y, double t) {
  double mt = 1-t;
  return new double[]{
    x[0]*mt*mt + 2*x[1]*mt*t + x[2]*t*t,
    y[0]*mt*mt + 2*y[1]*mt*t + y[2]*t*t
  };
}

double[] getTangent(double[] x, double[] y, double t) {
  double mt = t-1; // note: NOT 1-t
  return new double[]{
    2*(x[0]*mt - x[1]*(2*t-1) + x[2]*t),
    2*(y[0]*mt - y[1]*(2*t-1) + y[2]*t)
  };
}
```

Place your "thing" at the coordinate you get from `getPoint`, and then if you need it to follow your path, rotate your thing so that its axis of travel lines up with the tangent you get out of `getTangent`. Done.